# how to criteriabuilder check null

Tags: java, jpa

```
List<Predicate> predicatesList = new ArrayList<>();

predicatesList.add(cb.or((cb.notEqual(from.get(DISPLAY), STRING_NO)), (cb.equal(from.get(DISPLAY), null))));
```

I got exception while checking this. I what to check disply not equal to 'N' or display equals null.

```
(display!='N'or display is NULL)
```

If I change predicatesList to `predicates.add(cb.notEqual(from.get(DISPLAY), STRING_NO));` Then not get error. But I need to check null also.

Comment: Well, you are adding to `predicatesList` . But your list is called `predicates`maybe look at that. You are trying to add something to something that does exist.

Comment: I think there must be a `isNull()` method.

Comment: and maybe the exception said what the problem is ...

Comment: @OcelotcR sorry its my mistake. Now edited question

Comment: @Jens Can you please give example

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://book2s.com/java/api/javax/persistence/criteria/criteriabuilder/isnull-1.html

Comment: @Jens thank u so much

Comment: @user3431624 You are welcome

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I changed it to

```
predicates.add(cb.or((cb.notEqual(from.get(DISPLAY), STRING_NO)), (cb.isNull(from.get(DISPLAY)))));
```

Now It works fine. Thank you so much for helping me.